# Сравнение результатов запросов

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Делается запрос на сервер, сервер возвращает результат, результат записывается в диве.
Запрос делается каждые 5 секунд.
Мне надо как-то сравнить содержимое дива после каждого запроса с результатом предыдущего запроса.

```
function show(){

$.ajax({
 url: "../new_ajax.php",
 cache: false,
 dataType: "html",
 success: function(html) {
  $("#content").html(html);
 }
});

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте

```
 $.ajax({
 url: "../new_ajax.php",
 cache: false,
 dataType: "html",
 success: function(html) {
  var obj = $("#content").html();
if(obj == html){
Ваши_Действия
}
 }
});
```